# Add an element at the end of a list of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list

I have a list like this as an input:

```
{value: 1, rest: {value: 2, rest: null}}
```

I want to add an element to the list and place it in order to have this output:

```
{value: 1, rest: {value: 2, rest: {value 3, rest:null}}}
```

I managed to add the element at the beginning using the following function but how should I make it to add the element at the ending? Thanks.

```
function prepend(elem, list){

  list = {value:elem, rest:list};
  return list;
}
console.log(prepend(3, {value: 1, rest: {value: 2, rest: null}}));
```

The output is:  `{value: 3, rest: {value: 1, rest: {value 2, rest:null}}}`

Comment: That's an object, JS has no lists.

Comment: Is it necessary to have that object structure? An array of objects might be better for what you're doing.

Comment: I recommended Star_Man's answer. code is simple and wonderful. It can be used recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
I made a **recursive function**.

```
function prepend(elem, list){
   if (list.rest == null)
      list.rest = {value:elem, rest:null};
   else
     prepend(elem, list.rest);
   return list;
}
```

This function can be used in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop here and when i is last object or when rest is `null` add new object and break loop.

```js
var obj = {value: 1, rest: {value: 2, rest: null}}

function add(elem, list) {
  for (var i = obj; i; i = i.rest) {
    if (i.rest == null) {
      i.rest = { value: elem,rest: null}
      break;
    }
  }
}

add(3, obj)
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function append(list, item){
    if(list.rest == null)
    list.rest = item;
   else
    append(list.rest, item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use an array of objects and use `append()` in the array

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the `rest` objects and assign then the new object to the last.

```js
function prepend(elem, list) {
    var object = list;
    while (object.rest) {
        object = object.rest;
    }
    object.rest  = { value: elem, rest: null };
    return list;
}

console.log(prepend(3, { value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: null } }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/s8ju7fsv/2/) then:

```
var obj = {value: 1, rest: {value: 2, rest: null}};

function addRest(val) {
   var current = obj;
   while(current.rest) {
      current = current.rest;
   }
   current.rest = { value: val, rest: null };
}

addRest(3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
//{"value":1,"rest":{"value":2,"rest":{"value":3,"rest":null}}}
```

Comment: because the original problem is with objects, I made it look much simpler here

Answer (score 0):

Following code prints the output you want:

```js
'use strict';

var obj = {
    value: 1,
    rest: {
        value: 2,
        rest: null
    }
};

function append(elem, obj) {
    var iteratedObj = obj;
    while (iteratedObj.rest !== null) {
        iteratedObj = iteratedObj.rest;
    }

    iteratedObj.rest = elem;
}

var toBeAppended = {
    value: 3,
    rest: null
};

append(toBeAppended, obj);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should work in the particular case you described

```
function prepend(elem, list){

  for (var el in list) {
   el === 'rest' && list[el] === null ? list[el] = {value: elem, rest:null};
  }

  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function append(subHierarchy,hierarchy){
  var node=hierarchy;
  while(node.rest){
    node=node.rest
  }
  node.rest=subHierarchy;
  return hierarchy;
}

var result = append({value:4},{value:1,rest:{value:2,rest:{value:3}}});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is simple as below.

```
var elem = { ..... };
var obj = { ......... };
var rest = obj;

while(rest){
   rest = rest.rest;
}
rest = elem;
```

Comment: That doesn't work. You might as well remove all but the first and last lines.